# How to include correct: <SDL2/SDL.h> or <SDL.h> and set -I/usr/include/SDL2?

Tags: c++, include

How to include correct with using gcc: `<SDL2/SDL.h>` or `<SDL.h>` and set `-I/usr/include/SDL2`?

Comment: Why bother yourself with setting custom include path if /usr/include is default one, so former case works without extra tuning?

Answer (score 0):

Well, either are valid, but I think its far more polite to use that one that makes the compile command easier and more obvious, ie #include , thus you dont need to alter the include search path.

Answer (score 0):

I think this command will work:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers  -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2
```